# If $f(x)$ is an even function, and $f(g(x))$ is an even function, then $g(x)$ MUST be?

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

If $f(x)$ is an even function, and $f(g(x))$ is an even function, then $g(x)$ must be:

(a) odd

(b) even

(c) general

**(d) even or odd**

(e) even or general

(f) even or odd or general

This question is in one of my college textbooks and the answer to it was "even or odd", what I have a problem with is the use of the word MUST, because $g(x)$ doesn't have to be either odd or even for the function $f(g(x))$ to be even.
An example of this would be as follows:

$$
f(x) = \cos(x)
$$

$$
g(x) = x + \pi
$$

Then:

$$
h(x) = f(g(x)) = \cos(x + \pi) = -\cos(x)
$$

We can see that the function $h(x)$ is even, now is there something that I don't understand? or simply the choice of the word "must" was poor?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the exact text of the question you were asked. If the "must be" is with a question mark then a correct answer would be that, as you note, you can't say.

Comment: What is your question ? You gave a counterexample. Does the book really claim that $g$ must be even or odd ? Then , the author is simply wrong.

Comment: @EthanBolker Edited.

Comment: @Peter I edited my question and added the textbook question verbatim, my question is am I missing something?

Comment: The question in the book is poorly written. What does "general" mean? It  might mean "any function" but (f) suggests it means "neither even nor odd". Your correct example shows that in either case (d) is clearly wrong. The answers here show that (c) or (f) is correct, depending on the definitions. I do not understand the close and downvotes. This is a good question well asked (after the edits).

Comment: Thanks for the follow up feedback @EthanBolker, I really appreciate it! General means in my curriculum "neither odd nor even".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$g$ could be anything.

Take $f\equiv 0$.You have $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$ and also $f(g(x))=f(g(-x))$ for any function $g$.

**EDIT:** As Dominique pointed out in his comment, you can take $f$ to be any constant.

Comment: That's an interesting choice of a function, however what if we assume that f(x)≠0 and g(x)≠0

Comment: The author found a better counterexample (not the degenerate case of $f\equiv 0$) , so this answer is obsolete.

Comment: No sweat, just say that $f(x)=1$ :-)

Comment: Great, @Dominique!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that $g(x)=x$ (odd) and $f(x)=|x|$ (for $f(x)=|x|$ is an even function) are perfect counter-examples, aren't they? :-)